# How can I prevent an image I set as a profile picture inside of android studio from leaving once I go to a different screen or close the app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, image, save

I am using Android Studio and I am having issues saving an image to a screen. I have created the ability to upload an image to the screen using the phone's gallery but every time I go to a different activity or close the app, the image is gone. The image gets uploaded to firebase storage but does not remain on the screen when going to a different screen. I need a way for the app to retrieve the image and show it again. I was thinking of also trying sharedpreferences but I did not know if that would work. Here is the code:

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dci7i.png)
[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwRWA.png)

I was thinking of trying sharedpreferences.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).